# Adding ViewPager to custom View on Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-custom-view

I have a custom view looking like this

[image]

Is there a way to implement inner paging by ViewPager?
I tried to create VP this way:

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) viewPagerLayout.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    viewPager = new ViewPager(getContext());
    viewPager.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    viewPager.setId(View.generateViewId());
    viewPager.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

In OnDraw method:

```
viewPager.measure(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    viewPager.layout(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    if (viewPager != null)
        viewPager.draw(canvas);
```

Viewpager itself is drawn inside, like I want, but without paging ability. The method instantiateItem in adapter is never called. 
Standalone viewpager and adapter is working in another activity, but not inside custom view.

Comment: Why the canvas magic???

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I dont know how to do it another way ... this is my first try to make custom component with lot of custom animations. Would it be better to use some drawables or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your code I see you are "just drawing" `ViewPager` inside some method (`onDraw`?). it's like you are printing picture and want to talk with person on it... you have to add whole `ViewPager` to any container with `Context` to have ability to interact with it. thats why it is working straight inside `Activity` (which IS `Context`) or added by XML and not working when you just draw its "look"

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for explanation.